# Notifications when prepopulating circles Google+

Tags: google-plus, google-apps

Ok, another hickup in my quest for Google+ masterhood :)

I'm trying to pre-populate circles for users in my domain using the Google+ for domains API. This works fine, however all users (let's say 150) get notifications in Google+ that the other 149 users added them. Is there ANY way to disable these notifications when populating circles with the API? Otherwise it's not really helping... don't want to spam my user's notification bar!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can turn off these notifications currently. That seems like a reasonable feature request, you should [report it on the Google+ Platform issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).